# How to get second-highest salary employees in a table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, optimization

It's a question I got this afternoon:

There a table contains ID, Name, and Salary of Employees, get names of the second-highest salary employees, in SQL Server

Here's my answer, I just wrote it in paper and not sure that it's perfectly valid, but it seems to work:

```
SELECT Name FROM Employees WHERE Salary = 
( SELECT DISTINCT TOP (1) Salary FROM Employees WHERE Salary NOT IN
 (SELECT DISTINCT TOP (1) Salary FROM Employees ORDER BY Salary DESCENDING)
ORDER BY Salary DESCENDING)
```

I think it's ugly, but it's the only solution come to my mind.

Can you suggest me a better query?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

To get the names of the employees with the 2nd highest distinct salary amount you can use.

```
;WITH T AS
(
SELECT *,
       DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY Salary Desc) AS Rnk
FROM Employees
)
SELECT Name
FROM T
WHERE Rnk=2;
```

If Salary is indexed the following may well be more efficient though especially if there are many employees.

```
SELECT Name
FROM   Employees
WHERE  Salary = (SELECT MIN(Salary)
                 FROM   (SELECT DISTINCT TOP (2) Salary
                         FROM   Employees
                         ORDER  BY Salary DESC) T);
```

Test Script

```
CREATE TABLE Employees
  (
     Name   VARCHAR(50),
     Salary FLOAT
  )

INSERT INTO Employees
SELECT TOP 1000000 s1.name,
                   abs(checksum(newid()))
FROM   sysobjects s1,
       sysobjects s2

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX ix
  ON Employees(Salary)

SELECT Name
FROM   Employees
WHERE  Salary = (SELECT MIN(Salary)
                 FROM   (SELECT DISTINCT TOP (2) Salary
                         FROM   Employees
                         ORDER  BY Salary DESC) T);

WITH T
     AS (SELECT *,
                DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY Salary DESC) AS Rnk
         FROM   Employees)
SELECT Name
FROM   T
WHERE  Rnk = 2;

SELECT Name
FROM   Employees
WHERE  Salary = (SELECT DISTINCT TOP (1) Salary
                 FROM   Employees
                 WHERE  Salary NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT TOP (1) Salary
                                       FROM   Employees
                                       ORDER  BY Salary DESC)
                 ORDER  BY Salary DESC)

SELECT Name
FROM   Employees
WHERE  Salary = (SELECT TOP 1 Salary
                 FROM   (SELECT TOP 2 Salary
                         FROM   Employees
                         ORDER  BY Salary DESC) sel
                 ORDER  BY Salary ASC)
```

Answer (score 37):

```
SELECT * from Employee 
WHERE Salary IN (SELECT MAX(Salary) 
                 FROM Employee 
                 WHERE Salary NOT IN (SELECT MAX(Salary) 
                                      FFROM employee));
```

Try like this..

Comment: Why this answer got most of vote. Question is get Employees with 2nd Max salary. But this answer is giving only second highest salary, but not employee Details...

Comment: This approach is not very scalable. Imagine if you want to query 10th highest salaried employee! Better way is to order by salary & then limit records in output.

Answer (score 18):

This might help you

```
SELECT 
      MIN(SALARY) 
FROM 
      EMP 
WHERE 
      SALARY in (SELECT 
                      DISTINCT TOP 2 SALARY 
                 FROM 
                      EMP 
                 ORDER BY 
                      SALARY DESC
                )
```

We can find any `nth` highest salary by putting `n` (where `n > 0`) in place of `2`

Example for 5<sup>th</sup> highest salary we put `n = 5`

Answer (score 11):

How about a CTE?

```
;WITH Salaries AS
(
    SELECT Name, Salary,
       DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY Salary DESC) AS 'SalaryRank'
    FROM 
        dbo.Employees
)
SELECT Name, Salary
FROM Salaries  
WHERE SalaryRank = 2
```

`DENSE_RANK()` will give you all the employees who have the second highest salary - no matter how many employees have the (identical) highest salary.

Answer (score 10):

All of the following queries work for **MySQL**:

```
SELECT MAX(salary) FROM Employee WHERE Salary NOT IN (SELECT Max(Salary) FROM Employee);

SELECT MAX(Salary) From Employee WHERE Salary < (SELECT Max(Salary) FROM Employee);

SELECT Salary FROM Employee ORDER BY Salary DESC LIMIT 1 OFFSET 1;

SELECT Salary FROM (SELECT Salary FROM Employee ORDER BY Salary DESC LIMIT 2) AS Emp ORDER BY Salary LIMIT 1;
```

Answer (score 5):

Another intuitive way is :-
Suppose we want to find Nth highest salary then

1) Sort Employee as per descending order of salary

2) Take first N records using rownum. So in this step Nth record here is Nth highest salary

3) Now sort this temporary result in ascending order. Thus Nth highest salary is now first record

4) Get first record from this temporary result.

It will be Nth highest salary.

```
select * from 
 (select * from 
   (select * from  
       (select * from emp order by sal desc)  
   where rownum<=:N )  
 order by sal )
where rownum=1;
```

In case there are repeating salaries then in innermost query distinct can be used.

```
select * from 
 (select * from 
   (select * from  
       (select distinct(sal) from emp order by 1 desc)  
   where rownum<=:N )  
 order by sal )
where rownum=1;
```

Answer (score 5):

```
select MAX(Salary) from Employee WHERE Salary NOT IN (select MAX(Salary) from Employee );
```

Answer (score 5):

The simple way is to use **OFFSET**. Not only second, any position we can query using offset.

`SELECT SALARY,NAME FROM EMPLOYEE ORDER BY SALARY DESC LIMIT 1 OFFSET 1` --**Second** largest

`SELECT SALARY,NAME FROM EMPLOYEE ORDER BY SALARY DESC LIMIT 1 OFFSET 9` --For **10th** largest

Answer (score 4):

Simple way WITHOUT using any special feature specific to Oracle, MySQL etc.

Suppose EMPLOYEE table has data as below. Salaries can be repeated. 
[image]

By manual analysis we can decide ranks as follows :-
[image]

Same result can be achieved by query

```
select  *
from  (
select tout.sal, id, (select count(*) +1 from (select distinct(sal) distsal from     
EMPLOYEE ) where  distsal >tout.sal)  as rank  from EMPLOYEE tout
) result
order by rank
```

[image]

First we find out distinct salaries. 
Then we find out count of distinct salaries greater than each row. 
This is nothing but the rank of that id. 
For highest salary, this count will be zero. So '+1' is done to start rank from 1.

Now we can get IDs at Nth rank by adding where clause to above query.

```
select  *
from  (
select tout.sal, id, (select count(*) +1 from (select distinct(sal) distsal from     
EMPLOYEE ) where  distsal >tout.sal)  as rank  from EMPLOYEE tout
) result
where rank = N;
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you would want to use `DENSE_RANK` as you don't know how many employees have the same salary and you did say you wanted nameS of employees.

```
CREATE TABLE #Test
(
    Id INT,
    Name NVARCHAR(12),
    Salary MONEY
)

SELECT x.Name, x.Salary
FROM
        (
        SELECT  Name, Salary, DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY Salary DESC) as Rnk
        FROM    #Test
        ) x
WHERE x.Rnk = 2
```

`ROW_NUMBER` would give you unique numbering even if the salaries tied, and plain `RANK` would not give you a '2' as a rank if you had multiple people tying for highest salary. I've corrected this as `DENSE_RANK` does the best job for this.

Answer (score 2):

Below query can be used to find the nth maximum value, just replace 2 from nth number

```
select * from emp e1 where 2 =(select count(distinct(salary)) from emp e2
   where e2.emp >= e1.emp)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here I used two queries for the following scenarios which are asked during an interview
  First scenario:
  Find all second highest salary in the table (Second highest salary with more than 
  one employee )

```
select * from emp where salary
   In (select MAX(salary) from emp where salary NOT IN (Select MAX(salary) from 
   emp));
```

Second scenario:
  Find only the second highest salary in the table

```
select min(temp.salary) from (select * from emp order by salary desc limit 2) 
  temp;
```

Answer (score 2):

There are two way to do this first:

Use subquery to find the 2nd highest

```
SELECT MAX(salary) FROM employees
WHERE salary NOT IN (
SELECT MAX (salary) FROM employees)
```

But this solution is not much good as if you need to find out the 10 or 100th highest then you may be in trouble. So instead go for window function like

```
select * from
(
select salary,ROW_NUMBER() over( 
order by Salary desc) as
rownum from    employees
) as t where t.rownum=2
```

By using this method you can find out nth highest salary without any trouble.

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from emp where salary = (  
    select salary from   
       (select ROW_NUMBER() over (order by salary) as 'rownum', *
        from emp) t -- Order employees according to salary  
    where rownum = 2 -- Get the second highest salary
)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select max(age) from yd where age<(select max(age) from HK) ; /// True two table Highest 

SELECT * FROM HK E1 WHERE 1 =(SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT age) FROM HK E2 WHERE E1.age < E2.age); ///Second Hightest age RT single table 

select age from hk e1 where (3-1) = (select count(distinct (e2.age)) from yd e2 where e2.age>e1.age);//// same True Second Hight age RT two table

select max(age) from YD where age not in (select max(age) from YD);  //second hight age in single table
```

Comment: can you please add some explanations to your post (not only code)?

Answer (score 1):

Can we also use

```
select e2.max(sal), e2.name
from emp e2
where (e2.sal <(Select max (Salary) from empo el))
group by e2.name
```

Please let me know what is wrong with this approach

Comment: It will return all employes having a smaller than max salary, not just the second highest

Comment: This line: where (e2.sal <(Select max (Salary) from empo el))
does not do what you are expecting or what the OP is asking for.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT name
FROM employee
WHERE salary =
(SELECT MIN(salary) 
  FROM (SELECT TOP (2) salary
  FROM employee
  ORDER BY salary DESC) )
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * 
FROM TABLE1 AS A 
WHERE NTH HIGHEST NO.(SELECT COUNT(ATTRIBUTE) FROM TABLE1 AS B) WHERE B.ATTRIBUTE=A.ATTRIBUTE;
```

Answer (score 1):

this is the simple query .. if u want the second minimum then just change the max to min and change the less than(<) sign to grater than(>).

```
    select max(column_name) from table_name where column_name<(select max(column_name) from table_name)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this to get the respective nth highest salary.

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    emp e1
WHERE
    2 = (
        SELECT
            COUNT(salary)
        FROM
            emp e2
        WHERE
            e2.salary >= e1.salary
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT MAX(Salary) FROM Employee
WHERE Salary NOT IN (SELECT MAX(Salary) FROM Employee)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to display the name of the employee who is getting the second highest salary then use this:

```
SELECT employee_name 
FROM employee
WHERE salary = (SELECT max(salary) 
                FROM employee
                WHERE salary < (SELECT max(salary) 
                                FROM employee);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This one

```
    select * from
   (
    select name,salary,ROW_NUMBER() over( order by Salary desc) as
    rownum from    employee
   ) as t where t.rownum=2
```

http://askme.indianyouth.info/details/write-a-sql-query-to-find-the-10th-highest-employee-salary-from-an-employee-table-explain-your-answer-111

Answer (score 1):

`Select * from employee where salary = (Select max(salary) from employee where salary not in(Select max(salary)from employee))`

**Explanation :**

- **Query 1 :** Select max(salary) from employee where salary not in(Select max(salary) from employee) - This query will retrieve second highest salary
- **Query 2 :**  Select * from employee where  salary=(Query 1) - This query will retrieve all the records having second highest salary(Second highest salary may have multiple records)

Answer (score 0):

I think this is probably the simplest out of the lot.

```
SELECT Name FROM Employees group BY Salary DESCENDING limit 2;
```

Comment: Pay attention to the tags in the question; SQL Server doesn't support `LIMIT`.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**: This will give dynamic results irrespective of no of rows

```
SELECT * FROM emp WHERE salary = (SELECT max(e1.salary) 
FROM emp e1 WHERE e1.salary < (SELECT Max(e2.salary) FROM emp e2))**
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple approach:

```
select name
from employee
where salary=(select max(salary)
              from(select salary from employee
                   minus
                   select max(salary) from employee));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT `salary` AS emp_sal, `name` , `id`
FROM `employee`
GROUP BY `salary` ORDER BY `salary` DESC
LIMIT 1 , 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
declare

cntr number :=0;

cursor c1 is

select salary from employees order by salary desc;

z c1%rowtype;

begin

open c1;

fetch c1 into z;

while (c1%found) and (cntr <= 1) loop


cntr := cntr + 1;

fetch c1 into z;

dbms_output.put_line(z.salary);

end loop;

end;
```

Answer (score 0):

I want to post here possibly easiest solution. It worked in mysql.

Please check at your end too:

```
SELECT name
FROM `emp`
WHERE salary = (
SELECT salary
FROM emp e
ORDER BY salary DESC
LIMIT 1
OFFSET 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
    max(salary) 
from 
    emp_demo_table 
where 
    salary < (select max(salary) from emp_demo_table)
```

Hope this solves the query in simplest of terms.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Using this SQL, Second highest salary will get with Employee Name

```
Select top 1 start at 2 salary from employee group by salary order by salary desc;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 WITH CTE AS
 (
 SELECT DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY SALARY DESC)RN,* FROM Users
 )
 SELECT * FROM CTE WHERE RN=2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    salary
FROM
    Employee
ORDER BY
    salary DESC
LIMIT 1,
 1;
```

Comment: I had give common solution ( for mysql ), Not platform independent.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

```
 - Method 1

    select max(salary) from Employees
        where salary< (select max(salary) from Employees)



 - Method 2

 select MAX(salary) from Employees 
    where salary not in(select MAX(salary) from Employees)



 - Method 3

select MAX(salary) from Employees 
    where salary!= (select MAX(salary) from Employees )
```

Answer (score 0):

Creating temporary table

```
Create Table #Employee (Id int identity(1,1), Name varchar(500), Salary int)
```

Insert data

```
Insert Into #Employee
    Select 'Abul', 5000
Union ALL 
    Select 'Babul', 6000
Union ALL 
    Select 'Kabul', 7000
Union ALL 
    Select 'Ibul', 8000
Union ALL 
    Select 'Dabul', 9000
```

Query will be

```
select top 1 * from #Employee a
Where a.id <> (Select top 1 b.id from #Employee b ORDER BY b.Salary desc)
order by a.Salary desc
```

Drop table

```
drop table #Empoyee
```

Answer (score 0):

try this simple way

```
select name,salary from employee where salary =
(select max(salary) from employee where salary < (select max(salary) from employee ))
```

Comment: @forsvarir: please try to answer my question i.e. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30543744/create-trigger-taking-taking-too-much-time-on-phpmyadmin. 'Create trigger taking taking too much time on phpmyadmin'

Answer (score 0):

supose we have a table like

```
name       salary
 A           10
 B           30
 C           20
 D           40
```

so what we will do is first will arrange in descending order 40 30 20 10 =>

then we will take only first two number => 40 30

then we arrange it in ascending order => 30 40

then we will take the first number => 30

so in mysql ::

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT  * FROM employee   order by salary DESC LIMIT 2) order by salary ASC LIMIT 1;
```

in oracle ::

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT  * FROM employee  where rownum<=2 order by salary DESC )  where rownum<=1  order by salary ASC ;
```

Answer (score 0):

for nth highest salary. its easy way

```
select t.name,t.sal
from (select name,sal,dense_rank() over (order by sal desc) as rank from emp) t
where t.rank=6; //suppose i find 6th highest salary
```

Answer (score 0):

To find Second highest salary....

```
SELECT MAX( salary)  FROM tblEmp WHERE salary< ( SELECT MAX( salary) FROM tblEmp )
```

or

```
SELECT max(salary) FROM tblEmp WHERE salary NOT IN (SELECT max(salary) FROM tblEmp)
```

using CTE

```
;with cte
as 
(
Select *,dense_rank() over (order by salary desc) as rn from tblEmp
)
select * from cte where rn=2
```

where "salary" is column name and tblEmp is table Name...
both are working 100%...

Answer (score 0):

This query display all the details of the Employees with second highest salary

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    Employees
WHERE
    salary IN (
        SELECT
            max(salary)
        FROM
            Employees
        WHERE
            salary NOT IN (
                SELECT
                    max(salary)
                FROM
                    Employees
            )
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT MIN(a.sal) 
FROM dbo.demo a 
WHERE a.sal IN (SELECT DISTINCT TOP 2 a.sal 
                FROM dbo.demo a 
                ORDER BY a.sal DESC)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select * from (
   select ROW_NUMBER() over (order by [salary] desc) as sno,emp_name,   
   [salary] from [dbo].[Emp]
) t 
where t.sno =10

with t as
select top (1) * from       
  (select top (2) emp_name,salary from   [Emp]  e
   order by  salary desc) t
order  by salary asc
```

Answer (score 0):

A compilation of four solutions for the problem :

### First  Solution - Using Sub Query

SELECT MAX(salary) from Employee       ---- This query is going to give you max salary

Now use the above query as subquery to get next highest salary like below:

`SELECT MAX(salary) FROM employee WHERE salary <> (SELECT MAX(salary) from Employee)` -- This query is going to give you second highest salary

Now if you want to get name of employee(s) getting second highest salary, then use above query as sub-query to get it, like below

```
SELECT name from employee WHERE salary = 
(SELECT MAX(salary) FROM employee WHERE salary <> (SELECT MAX(salary) from Employee)
```

-- This query is going to give you second highest salary)

### Second Solution - Using Derived Table

`SELECT TOP 2 DISTINCT(salary) FROM employee ORDER BY salary DESC`  -- This is going to give you two highest salary. What you are doing here is to order the salaries in descending order and then select the top 2 salaries.

Now order the above result set in ascending order by salary, and get TOP 1

```
SELECT TOP 1 salary FROM
(SELECT TOP 2 DISTINCT(salary) FROM employee ORDER BY salary DESC) AS tab 
ORDER BY salary
```

### Third Solution - Using correlated sub query

```
SELECT name, salary FROM Employee e WHERE 2=(SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT salary) FROM Employee p WHERE e.salary<=p.salary)
```

### Fourth Solution - Using window function

```
;WITH T AS
(
SELECT *, DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY Salary Desc) AS Rnk
FROM Employees
)
SELECT Name
FROM T
WHERE Rnk=2;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one for MSSQL:

```
SELECT
    TOP 1 salary
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            TOP 2 salary
        FROM
            Employees 
    ) sal
ORDER BY
    salary DESC;
```

But you should try this generic SQL query which is working for all kinds of database.

```
SELECT
    MAX(salary)
FROM
    Employee
WHERE
    Salary NOT IN (
        SELECT
            Max(Salary)
        FROM
            Employee
    );
```

**OR**

```
SELECT
    MAX(Salary)
FROM
    Employee
WHERE
    Salary < (
        SELECT
            Max(Salary)
        FROM
            Employee
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT lastname, firstname
FROM employees
WHERE salary IN(
    SELECT MAX(salary) 
    FROM employees 
    WHERE salary < (SELECT MAX(salary) FROM employees));
```

So here is what the code mentioned above does:

It returns the last names followed by the first names of the employees
that have a salary that is smaller than the max salary of all the employees but it's also the max salary of the rest employees that don't have the max salary.

In other words: It returns the names of the employees that have the second maximum salary.

Comment: **From review queue**: May I request you to please add some more context around your answer. Code-only answers are difficult to understand. It will help the asker and future readers both if you can add more information in your post.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions @RBT. I added more context around my answer as you requested!

Answer (score 0):

i have a table like this in this below image,and i am going to find the 2nd largest number in "to_user" column..
[image]

Here is Answer

> select MAX(to_user) FROM db.masterledger where to_user NOT IN (SELECT
>   MAX(to_user) FROM db.masterledger);

Answer (score 0):

Most of the answers are valid. You can use offset with sorted salary as below,

```
SELECT NAME
FROM EMPLOYEES
WHERE SALARY IN
(
    SELECT DISTINCT 
           SALARY
    FROM EMPLOYEES
    ORDER BY SALARY DESC
    OFFSET 1 ROWS FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY
);
```

To find nth highest salary, replace offset 1 by n

Answer (score 0):

You can use distinct (For returning Null values when the select statement returns NULL value & removing duplicates) and Limit OFFSET for getting the second element

```
select (select distinct(salary) 
from Employee
order by salary desc
limit 1, 1)
as SecondHighestSalary;
```

Limit 1,1 ---> First 1 denotes OFFSET and the second 1 denotes Number of rows to be returned.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one more using `dense_rank()`

```
select * from (select name, salary, dense_rank() over(order by salary desc)r from employee)) where r=n
```

Here in your case 'n' is 2

Answer (score -1):

```
select MAX(Salary) from Employee WHERE Salary <> (select MAX(Salary) from Employee )
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this query for `2ndHighest` salary:

```
SELECT MIN(salary) AS '2ndHighest'
  FROM tbl_Emp
  WHERE salary IN (SELECT TOP 2 salary FROM tbl_Emp ORDER BY 1 DESC)
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
SELECT min(salary) 
FROM employee 
WHERE salary IN (SELECT top 2 salary FROM employee ORDER BY salary DESC)
```

Comment: While code-only answers are not forbidden, please understand that this is a Q&A community, rather than a crowd-sourcing one, and that, usually, if the OP understood the code being posted as an answer, he would have come up with a similar solution, and wouldn't have posted a question in the first place. As such, please provide *context* to your answer and/or code by explaining *how* and/or *why* it works.

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT *,DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY Salary Desc) AS Rnk
INTO #tmp1
FROM Employees

SELECT * FROM #tmp1 WHERE Rnk = 2
DROP TABLE #tmp1


SELECT Name,SALARY
FROM  Employees
WHERE  Salary = (SELECT MIN(Salary)
             FROM   (SELECT DISTINCT TOP (2) Salary
                     FROM   Employees
                     ORDER  BY Salary DESC) T);
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM emptable 
WHERE empid IN (
    SELECT sal,row_number () ( OVER partition by sal order by sal desc) RN
    FROM emptable
    WHERE RN=2)
```

Answer (score -3):

```
select max(sal) , Department no. from employee where sal<max(sal)
```

Answer (score -3):

```
select salary from table order by salary desc limit 1,1
```

note:this works only for MYSQL

Comment: "limit 1" is not valid in SQL Server