# How to get Nth big item

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I am getting 11th older person from users table with the following SQL statement

```
select MAX(age) 
from ( select * 
       from (select * 
             from users 
             order by age asc)  
       where rownum <12)
```

is there a simplified and efficient query to get 11th older person with full information?

USING 
Oracle 11G

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7417415/how-to-get-second-highest-salary-employees-in-a-table

Comment: could you tag the rdbms you are using?

Comment: my database is oracle 11g

Comment: you can remove that outer query, and change the second `SELECT *` to `SELECT MAX(age)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
WITH AgeOrderedPersons AS (
    SELECT usr.*
          ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Age) AS Number
    FROM Users usr
)
SELECT *
FROM AgeOrderedPersons
WHERE Number = 11
```

If you want all users with same age use `DENSE_RANK()` instead of `ROW_NUMBER()`

Comment: it is not so efficient, I have compared your and mine sql statement. my SQL is nearly three times better performance than yours.

Answer (score 0):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/2b1ed/4)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE users ( age, x ) AS
          SELECT 20, 1 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 80, 2 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 47, 3 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 33, 4 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 24, 5 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 7, 6 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 102, 7 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 99, 8 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 90, 9 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 28, 10 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 46, 11 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 54, 12 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 67, 13 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 17, 14 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 34, 15 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 32, 16 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 39, 17 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 26, 18 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 15, 19 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 12, 20 FROM DUAL;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
       NTH_VALUE( age, 11 ) IGNORE NULLS OVER ( ORDER BY age ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING ) AS age,
       NTH_VALUE( x,   11 ) IGNORE NULLS OVER ( ORDER BY age ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING ) AS x
FROM   users
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/2b1ed/4/0)**:

```
| AGE |  X |
|-----|----|
|  34 | 15 |
```

**Query 2**:

Include an ordering clause in the statement with `ROW_NUMBER()`:

```
WITH ranked AS (
  SELECT u.*,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY age ) AS rn
  FROM   users u
  ORDER BY age
)
SELECT age, x
FROM   ranked
WHERE  rn = 11
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/2b1ed/4/1)**:

```
| AGE |  X |
|-----|----|
|  34 | 15 |
```

**Query 3**:

```
WITH ordered AS (
  SELECT *
  FROM   users
  ORDER BY age
),
ranked AS (
  SELECT o.*,
         ROWNUM AS rn
  FROM   ordered o
  WHERE  ROWNUM <= 11
)
SELECT age, x
FROM   ranked
WHERE  rn = 11
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/2b1ed/4/2)**:

```
| AGE |  X |
|-----|----|
|  34 | 15 |
```