# Get second max highest mark and name

Tags: sql

Consider a table with two columns: `mark` and `name`

I need to get the second highest value, and the name of the second highest value.

Comment: What have you already tried? What are you having trouble with? SQL Server, MySQL, etc?

Comment: Possible duplicate of (**MySQL**) [Find max and second max salary for a employee table MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21520038/find-max-and-second-max-salary-for-a-employee-table-mysql), (**SQL Server**) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7417415/how-to-get-second-highest-salary-employees-in-a-table, (**Oracle**) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16293298/how-can-i-select-the-record-with-the-2nd-highest-salary-in-database-oracle

Answer (score 1):

You can use ROW_NUMBER(), RANK(), DENSE_RANK() functions in SQL.
But in this case, you'll have to use DENSE_RANK() because there may be  a condition where 2 or more students may have scored maximum marks, in such case you can't use ROW_NUMBER() or RANK().

Learn more about this functions [click here](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/rank-denserank-and-rownumber-functions-in-sql-server/)

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT name, mark, DENSE_RANK() over (order by mark desc) RankNo 
    FROM tablename
    ) AS Result 
WHERE Result.RankNo = 2
```

Comment: I'd remove the brackets in `[RankNo]` in order to get a standard SQL query. You can make it `AS RankNo` to get it more readable.

Comment: actually I was using [Rank] but then I thought using keyword under sqaure brackets can misguide him. Anyways thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * 
FROM   (SELECT name, 
               mark, 
               Row_number() over(ORDER BY mark DESC) AS rownums 
        FROM   employees) 
WHERE  rownums = 2;
```

Comment: Please provide some context for your answer : https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT name,mark FROM table ORDER BY mark desc limit 1,1
```

This code sort all records by `mark` in descending order. `limit 1,1` skips the first result (first `1` = first record) and then returns the next result (second `1` = second record).